How to construct a point on a semicircle such that one chord is twice the other?
The Problem: Given a semicircle with diameter $AB$ construct a point $C$ on the semicircle such that $BC = 2AC$.

How to construct such point?

Assuming you mean using a ruler and compass only, construct a line perpendicular to $AB$ at $A$ and make the length of this line the same as the radius of the blue circle. Mark this endpoint $X$. Then the line $BX$ meets the blue circle at the required point $C$.

It does work, but why does it work? Is there a proof for that?

Because you need $ \angle{CBA}$ to ne $\arctan\frac12$

@Rusurano the altitude of a right triangle creates 3 similar triangles from the original, this construct reverses that and uses $AC$ as the altitude and fills out the full triangle with the needed proportions.

If A is $(0,0)$ and B is $(1,0)$ then let $D=(-1,0)$ and $E=(1/3,0)$. Draw a circle with $DE$ as diameter and this circle intersects the circle with diameter $AB$ at $C$.

This answer would be more helpful if it indicated the how/why of it.

Let $H$ be the projection of $C$ on $AB$. By similar triangles
($BHC\sim ABC\sim AHC$) we have:
$$
BH={BC^2\over AB}=4{AC^2\over AB}=4AH.
$$
Hence $AH={1\over5}AB$.
